# Confidence interval around the line in a random coefficient model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, confidence-interval, estimation

I have measurements of some $y$ taken at times $1,\ldots,k$ for several individuals and the dependecy of $y$ on time seems to be adequately described by a linear function. To account for the repeated measurement nature in the data, I have fitted a random coefficient model, i.e.
$$
y_{ij}=(\alpha+a_i)+(\beta+b_i)t_{ij}+\varepsilon_{ij},
$$
where $(\alpha,\beta)$ are the fixed effects and $(a_i,b_i)$ are the random effects and $t_{ij}$ is the time at the $j$th measurement for the $i$th individual.

In Stata this is: mixed y c.time || ID: time, cov(un)

Now I really want to accompany the estimated line with 95% confidence bounds but I'm struggling to find an expression for the standard error of the estimated line at a given time point $t$.

I know that for an ordinary linear regression, the standard error is given by
$$
\mathrm{SE}(\hat{\alpha}+\hat{\beta}t)=\sigma\sqrt{\frac1n+\frac{(t-\bar{t})^2}{\sum(t_i-\bar{t})^2}},
$$
where $n$ is the sample size. How does this formula extend to the random coefficient model? And how is this obtained in Stata?